# Restarting an app on linux using c# while using screen

Tags: c#, mono

I have a c# application I run on a linux vps using mono. I need to restart it every now and then, after every 20 minutes to be exact.

So far I have been using

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mono", "app.exe");
```

Now, I want it to run along with screen as well so I tried doing

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("screen" "mono app.exe");
```

But that doesn't seem to work. What can I do?

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is Screen not starting? Is Screen starting but not mono? Is Screen and mono starting, but not your app?

Comment: The app just doesn't start apparently or something, also, using screen -ls returns nothing.